# cannot locate JQuery UI accordion div in the right place

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

Just want to display F.A.Q. page using Jquery UI accordion.I have several Paragraphs (FAQ Titles) and each of them includes a group of questions and answers.Firstly, I display the list of FAQ Titles.
When I click on one of them, the relevant group of questions and answers appears in Accordion style.The only problem is that it displays that accordion div under the whole list of FAQ Titles like in the image below but I want it to display each accordion div under the relevant FAQ title.Could you please check my code below.

[image]

Here is My view

```
<div class="abc">
    <?php echo $message; foreach($results as $row){ $faq_title=$ row->faq_title; ?>
    <h3><a href="#" class="faq_title"><?php echo $faq_title; ?></a></h3>

    <?php }?>
    <div id="accordion"></div> 
</div>
```

Here is my JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#accordion").accordion({ 
        collapsible: true
    });

    $(".faq_title").click(function () {
        var title = $(this).text();

        $.post('cont/get_data', {
            title: title
        }, function (data) {

            var my_obj = data;
            $.each(my_obj, function (i) {

                var question = my_obj[i].faq_question;
                var answer = my_obj[i].faq_answer;

                var dynaContent = "<h3><a href='#' class='question'>" + question + "</a></h3>" +
                    "<div class='answer'>" + answer + "</div>";

                $("#accordion").append(dynaContent); 
                $('#accordion').accordion("refresh"); 
            });
        }, "json");

        $("#accordion").html(""); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not including the accordion content element in your loop. The docs call for an element to exist under each heading:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>First header</h3>
    <div>First content panel</div>

    <h3>Second header</h3>
    <div>Second content panel</div>
</div>
```

In your case, it might look like this:

```
<div class="abc">
    <?php echo $message; foreach($results as $row){ $faq_title=$ row->faq_title; ?>
    <h3><a href="#" class="faq_title"><?php echo $faq_title; ?></a></h3>

    <div class="content-panel"></div>
    <?php }?>
</div>
```

You'd also need to modify your jQuery to use DOM traversal instead of targeting an ID:

```
$(this).next('.content-panel').html(dynaContent);
```

Be sure to use a class, and not an ID, which would result in an invalid duplicate ID scenario.

Comment: I have just edited my code in the way you described (please see my updated question) and now accordion div cannot be displayed at all. Could you please check what is wrong with the code?

Comment: My suggestions were not intended to fit exactly into your code. You'll need to work through the rest of the changes. For example, there's no reason to rewrite the entire H3 element every time. Why not just change its text value?